# Custom Loss Function in Keras (R language)

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, finance

I must create a custom loss function in R using Keras.
My loss function in R language is trivial:

```
lossTradingReturns = function(y_true, y_pred) {
  y_true_diff = na.trim(diff(log(y_true)))
  y_pred_diff = na.trim(diff(log(y_pred)))
  sum( -(sign(y_pred_diff) * y_true_diff) )
}
```

I translated it in Keras for R as follow:

```
lossTradingReturns = function(y_true, y_pred) {
   y_true_log = k_log(y_true)
   y_pred_log = k_log(y_pred)
   y_true_diff = y_true_log[2:batch_size] - y_true_log[1:(batch_size-1)]
   y_pred_diff = y_pred_log[2:batch_size] - y_pred_log[1:(batch_size-1)]
   y_true_diff = k_reshape(y_true_diff, (batch_size-1))
   y_pred_diff = k_reshape(y_pred_diff, (batch_size-1))
   return (k_sum( -(k_sign(y_pred_diff) * y_true_diff) ))
}
```

My function make differencing (y_t - y_t0) so I start with 1024 elements (batch_size) but at the end I have just 1023 elements to calculate return.
The error message indicate me that it needs 1024, I don't understand why: the function must return just a scalar...

Anyway if I'm wrong and it is correct that function output must but a 1024 tensor how can I extend my 1023 tensor adding a zero value?

Thanks in advance

*Error message at runtime:*

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 1024 values, but the requested shape has 1023
[[Node: loss_19/dense_2_loss/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss_19/dense_2_loss/Sub, loss_19/dense_2_loss/Reshape_1/shape)]]

Caused by op u'loss_19/dense_2_loss/Reshape', defined at:
File "/home/peroni/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 863, in compile
**kwargs)
File "/home/peroni/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 830, in compile
sample_weight, mask)
```

To clarify my strategy after comments received: batch samples are contiguous by design but I'm checking to be sure about that! (thanks for suggestion). This is the function I used (shuffle=FALSE) to select them. Perhaps your can confirm it to me.

```
# data — The original array of floating-point data, which you normalized in listing 6.32.
# lookback — How many timesteps back the input data should go.
# delay — How many timesteps in the future the target should be.
# min_index and max_index — Indices in the data array that delimit which timesteps to draw from. This is useful for keeping a segment of the data for validation and another for testing.
# shuffle — Whether to shuffle the samples or draw them in chronological order.
# batch_size — The number of samples per batch.
# step — The period, in timesteps, at which you sample data. You’ll set it 6 in order to draw one data point every hour.
generator = function(data, Y.column=1, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index, shuffle = FALSE, batch_size = 128, step = 6, is_test = FALSE) {
  if (is.null(max_index))
    max_index <- nrow(data) - delay - 1
  i <- min_index + lookback
  function() {
    if (shuffle) {
      rows <- sample(c((min_index+lookback):max_index), size = batch_size)
    } else {
      if (i + batch_size >= max_index)
        i <<- min_index + lookback
      rows <- c(i:min(i+batch_size-1, max_index))
  i <<- i + length(rows)
    }
    samples <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows), 
                                lookback / step,
                                dim(data)[[-1]]-1))
    targets <- array(0, dim = c(length(rows)))

    for (j in 1:length(rows)) {
      indices <- seq(rows[[j]] - lookback, rows[[j]]-1, 
                     length.out = dim(samples)[[2]])
      samples[j,,] <- data[indices, -Y.column]
      targets[[j]] <- data[rows[[j]] + delay, Y.column]
    }            

    if (!is_test)
      return (list(samples, targets))
    else
      return (list(samples))
  }
}
```

I evaluated the hypotesis of differentiate signals before (to make them stationary) but this changes a lot my NN working strategy and it causes very lower performances...

Answer (score 1):

The error happens in `k_reshape`. However your loss function doesn't need this reshape step, because `k_sum` take the mean across all elements of the tensor if you leave `axis=NULL`.

The following loss function works fine for me:

```
lossTradingReturns = function(y_true, y_pred) {
   y_true_log = k_log(y_true)
   y_pred_log = k_log(y_pred)
   y_true_diff = y_true_log[2:batch_size] - y_true_log[1:(batch_size-1)]
   y_pred_diff = y_pred_log[2:batch_size] - y_pred_log[1:(batch_size-1)]
   return (k_sum( -(k_sign(y_pred_diff) * y_true_diff) ))
}
```

However this loss function looks very odd to me. The dataset is shuffled during training, so that the mini-batches are not the same in each epoch. So taking the difference of y inside the loss function doesn't make sense, because the observations that are substracted are completely random. Shouldn't you rather be differentiating your y variable in the whole dataset at once before training the model?

Comment: Pierre, thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately the function you suggested doesn't work. It returns the following error:

 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1023,1] vs. [1024,1]
     [[Node: loss/dense_1_loss/Mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](loss/dense_1_loss/Sign, loss/dense_1_loss/Sub)]]

Caused by op u'loss/dense_1_loss/Mul', defined at:
  File "/home/peroni/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 863, in compile
    **kwargs)

Comment: To clarify my strategy: batch samples are contiguous by design (please see my original post edited) but I'm checking to be sure about that! (thanks for suggestion).
I evaluated the hypotesis of differentiate signals before (to make them stationary) but this changes a lot my NN working strategy and it causes very lower performances...